# Python: Remote debug problem on Raspberry Pi (SSH) using VS Code Insiders

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, configuration, raspberry-pi

I want to debug remotely a Python script on my Raspberry Pi via VS Code Insiders using SSH. 
So far I can connect to the Pi and see the Pi's folder and file content.

Now when I want to start debugging a script nothing happens. I assume a problem in the debug configuration, as the /home/pi/.vscode/launch.json file is empty. Can anyone help me what should be the content of the file? I also reinstalled Python but it doesnt helped.

This is the launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
}
```

Thanks in advance
Pepper

VS Code Insiders Version: 1.45.0
Python Version: 2020.3.71659

Comment: Remote debugging is documented at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-debugging.

Comment: I solved the problem. The cause was an automatically started Python script which I launched after the boot process via **/etc/profile**
The endless script blocked the terminal and no other debug session could be started. 
Now I start the mentioned Python script via **crontab**